# Bash confirm input or re enter

Tags: bash, prompt

I have a very simple BASH script that asks the user if they would like to enter some input. The response is `y` or `n`

If they enter `n` the script exits.

If they enter `y` then they are asked some questions. At the end I want to ask them to confirm the input.

If it's correct we'll carry on, if not I want to return them to the questions to re enter the information.

So far I've got:

```
while true; do
    echo -e "Enter details ? "
    read yn
    case $yn in
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        [Yy]* ) 
            echo -e "description"
            read desc

            echo -e "Address"
            read address

        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

This seems to work fine, so I've tried to add the confirmation.. but thats not working.

```
while true; do
    echo -e "Enter details ? "
    read yn
    case $yn in
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        [Yy]* ) 
            echo -e "description"
            read desc

            echo -e "Address"
            read address

            echo -e "$desc - $address"

            while true; do
                echo -e "\nAre these details correct ? "
                read conf
                case $conf in
                    [Nn]* ) // return to enter details //
                    [Yy]* ) // carry on with the details entered // break;;
                esac
            done


        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

The aim is as follows

The user selects `y` and enters description and address. The page shows them a summary of what they've entered and asks them `are these details correct ?` if they are we move on and the script progresses. The the input is wrong then the script returns them to enter description followed by enter address.

Can someone advise how to do this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add one more loop level and use the optional level indicator of `break [n]`:

```
while true; do
    echo -e "Enter details ? "
    read yn
    case $yn in
        [Nn]*) exit;;
        [Yy]*)
            while true; do
                echo -e "description"
                read desc

                echo -e "Address"
                read address

                echo -e "$desc - $address"

                while true; do
                    echo -e "\nAre these details correct ? "
                    read conf
                    case $conf in
                        [Nn]* ) break 1;;
                        [Yy]* ) break 3;;
                    esac
                done
            done;;
        *) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: thanks for my sanity could you confirm where break1 & break3 break out to.

Comment: `break 1` is the same as `break`: it exits the innermost loop. `break 3`, in this case exits the outermost loop.

Comment: Quick follow up on this. If they answer no the details aren't correct, we go back to the loop but how do we autofill the questions with their last answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `case` for this.
Script for example for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    echo -e "Enter details ?(y/n)"
    read yn
    if [[ $yn == "y" ]];then
            echo -e "description"
            read desc

            echo -e "Address"
            read address

            echo -e "$desc - $address"

            while true; do
                echo -e "\nAre these details correct ? (y/n)"
                read conf
                if [[ $conf == "y" ]];then
                    echo "All done"
                    break
                elif [[ $conf == "n" ]];then
                    break
                else
                    continue
                fi
            done
    elif [[ $yn == "n" ]];then
        break
    else
        continue
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
DONE=""
while [ "$DONE" != "true" ]; do
    echo -e "Enter details ? "
    read yn
    case $yn in
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        [Yy]* )
            echo -e "description"
            read desc

            echo -e "Address"
            read address

            echo -e "$desc - $address"

            while true; do
                echo -e "\nAre these details correct ? "
                read conf
                case $conf in
                    [Nn]* )
                        break;;
                    [Yy]* )
                        echo "doing something with your values"
                        DONE="true"
                        break;;
                esac
            done
        ;;


        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```